# How to find all smart contracts which supports specific interface on ethereum？

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

for example, I write a custom solidity interface

```
interface IMyInterface is IERC165{
}
```

Is there a way to find all smart contracts which is `IMyInterface` compatible deployed on the net?

It could be useful in some scenario like:

- If I want to build a NFT marketplace, I can use this way to find all NFT collections to query all `IERC721`

There are some existing apis for NFT collections like

- https://moralis.io/api/nft/
- https://www.alchemy.com/nft-api

But I can not find any api which supports like non-ERC contracts

Answer (score 1):

I find out that it's impossible to complete this

The code is compiled as bytecode in EVM.

The NFT marketplace listen to IERC721 `Transfer` event to discover NFTs

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72430527/15527691

Answer (score 1):

Actually you **can** check if the contract's bytecode fulfills the interface.

- get the opcodes from the bytecode
- filter by `PUSH4` and data - the method signatures.
- get method signatures from your interface
- check if all method signatures can be found in opcodes data

The implementation example from [0xWeb/evm::checkInterfaceOf](https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto/blob/12cb5b47e4a233407e69535cc064055ccd286c7a/src/evm/EVM.ts#L155) and usage:

```js
const contractAddress = `0x....`;
const bytecode = await web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress);
const evm = new EVM(bytecode);
const { ok, missing } = await evm.checkInterfaceOf([
    'upgradeTo(address)',
    'implementation()',
]);
```

Another question is how to get all the contracts.

- index the transaction to find out the contract creation transactions and `create2` calls from trace logs. This is the most difficult part.
- index contracts, as you mentioned, by fetching the event logs by some specific `topic`.